# Can not access shared folder sharing file

Tags: 16.04, permissions, file-sharing

i am beginner in ubuntu in my computer i have ubuntu 16.04 LTS i am facing issue with file sharing from my another computer i am shared one folder in that i have parent folder also i can do file change in main folder but i can not do changes in file of my parent folder.

can any one tell what i have to do why i can not do change in parent folder files

[image: Error shown during save]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you sharing using Samba (windoze file sharing) or SSH or what?

Comment: I am using samba...